# Reloading UIViewController from scratch via AppDelegate applicationWillEnterForeground

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

What I'm looking for is a very straightforward solution to the following in my XCode project:
When `applicationWillEnterForeground` is called, I want my main (and only) `viewcontroller` to reload as if the app is launching from scratch, the reason being I want it to recalculate a number of things at that point which might have changed while the app was in the background, in response to temporal changes detected when the app is launched. I want this to happen rather than the view just to reappear in its last seen state

The `viewcontroller` is named `TMViewController`

I have found answers that tell me simply that I have to reload the `viewcontroller` in the `applicationWillEnterForeground` section of the AppDelegate, but not how to do this

I have found answers that explain how to reload various elements, labels, webviews, and data from the net. These are much more complex than I need, and I can't really see the needle for the haystack

All I need to happen is the `applicationWillEnterForeground` to reload the `viewcontroller` as if its `viewDidLoad` had been called (I understand that this in itself is not a good solution, not that I know how to do even that!)

I suppose in a nutshell I'm struggling to understand what needs to go in the h & m files of both the `AppDelegate` and the `viewcontroller` files to accomplish this

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
self.window.rootViewController = [[TMViewController alloc]intWithNibName:@"myNib" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: but where do I put that?

Comment: in - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application - as per your question, "I have found answers that tell me simply that I have to reload the viewcontroller in the applicationWillEnterForeground section of the AppDelegate, but not how to do this" :)

Comment: I tried that but I get: !No visible@interface for 'TMViewController' declares the selector 'intWithNibName:bundle:'

Comment: I realise I'm probably missing something elsewhere that's really simple, the whole app is written and I'm really stuck on this point though.